# Can't get desired result from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query in MySQL with output in PHP, but it's proving rather difficult.

I have a table with 3 columns (yes I know the database layout for this isn't the best, but I can't change this, the client has other software using this db with this exact layout)

```
Amount - Product - Package 
2      - Apple   - Fruitbasket1
1      - Pear    - Fruitbasket1
5      - Grape   - Fruitbasket1
2      - Apple   - Fruitbasket2
1      - Pear    - Fruitbasket2
9      - Banana  - Fruitbasket2
```

So far I came up with this:

```
SELECT package 
FROM `data` 
WHERE package IN 
(
  SELECT package 
  FROM `data` 
  WHERE product = 'apple' AND amount = '2'
) 
AND package IN 
(
  SELECT package 
  FROM `data` 
  WHERE product = 'pear' AND amount ='1'
) 
AND package IN 
(
  SELECT package 
  FROM `data` 
  WHERE product = 'grape' AND amount = '5'
) 
LIMIT 0,1
```

The issue is that when the customer would fill out "apple" and "2" on the form, it would return all the baskets containing 2 apples. What I need is a statement that will only accept the exact products and their amounts to return the one basket those ingredients belong to, or nothing at all.

So even though 1 pear and 2 apples are in Fruitbasket1, it should not give Fruitbasket1 as a result if the other part, namely 5 grapes, are not specified by the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query will return all packages where the only product is 2 Apples

```
select package from `data`
group by package
having count(case when amount = 2 and product = 'Apple' then 1 end) = 1
and count(*) = 1
```

if you want 1 pear and 2 apples for example

```
select package from `data`
group by package
having count(
  case 
    when (amount = 2 and product = 'Apple') or (amount = 1 and product = 'Pear') 
    then 1 
  end) = 2
and count(*) = 2
```

you could also write this as

```
select package from `data`
group by package
having count(case when amount = 2 and product = 'Apple' then 1 end) = 1
   and count(case when amount = 1 and product = 'Pear' then 1 end) = 1
   and count(*) = 2
```

Comment: This statement does not yield any results, sadly.

Comment: @RudyvanSloten can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: +1. @RudyvanSloten: Given the sample data, we would expect this query to return exactly zero rows, because there is no `package` that has only `'2 Apple'` and `'1 Pear'`. To get this query to return a row, we'd also need add: **`or (amount = 5 and product = 'Grape')`**, and change both of the **`= 2`** to **`= 3`** to get it to "match" `Fruitbasket1`. I believe the query provided by FuzzyTree meets the specification.

Comment: @spencer7593 I made a small typo. My fault :(

Answer (score 2):

I only have Oracle handy so you may have to adjust the syntax somewhat, but following your original style I've added a "not in" section to make sure the basket contains only the fruits you are looking for. Here are some inserts with a couple of examples:

```
create table data (amount integer, product varchar(12), package varchar(16));

insert into data values (2, 'Apple', 'Fruitbasket1');
insert into data values (1, 'Pear', 'Fruitbasket1');
insert into data values (5, 'Grape', 'Fruitbasket1');
insert into data values (2, 'Apple', 'Fruitbasket2');
insert into data values (1, 'Pear', 'Fruitbasket2');
insert into data values (9, 'Banana', 'Fruitbasket2');
insert into data values (2, 'Apple', 'Fruitbasket3');
insert into data values (2, 'Apple', 'Fruitbasket4');
insert into data values (1, 'Pear', 'Fruitbasket4');


SELECT package 
FROM data 
WHERE package IN 
(
  SELECT package 
  from data 
  WHERE product = 'Apple' AND amount = '2'
)
and package not in
(
  SELECT package 
  from data 
  WHERE product <> 'Apple'
)
group by package
;


SELECT package 
FROM data 
WHERE package IN 
(
  SELECT package 
  from data 
  WHERE product = 'Apple' AND amount = '2'
) 
AND package IN 
(
  SELECT package 
  FROM data 
  WHERE product = 'Pear' AND amount ='1'
) 
and package not in
(
  SELECT package 
  from data 
  WHERE product <> 'Apple' and product <> 'Pear'
)
group by package
;
```

Comment: I'll give yours a go too, but FuzzyTree has provided a more concise line :)

Comment: Yep, totally Agree :)